# plotting high precision data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an array which contains error values as a function of two different  quantities (alpha and eigRange).

I fill my array like this :

```
   for j in range(n): 
        for i in range(alphaLen):
            alpha = alpha_list[i]
            c = train.eig(xt_, yt_,m-j, m,alpha, "cpu")
            costListTrain[j, i] = cost.err(xt_, xt_, yt_, c)

   normedValues=costListTrain/np.max(costListTrain.ravel())
```

where

```
n = 20
alpha_list = [0.0001,0.0003,0.0008,0.001,0.003,0.006,0.01,0.03,0.05]
```

My `costListTrain` array contains some values that have very small differences,  e.g.:

> 2.809458902485728   2.809458905776425   2.809458913576337   2.809459011062461
>      2.030326752376704   2.030329906064879   2.030337351188699   2.030428976282031
>      1.919840839066182   1.919846470077076   1.919859731440199   1.920021453630778
>      1.858436351617677   1.858444223016128   1.858462730482461   1.858687054377165
>      1.475871326997542   1.475901926855846   1.475973476249240   1.476822830933632
>      1.475775410801635   1.475806023102173   1.475877601316863   1.476727286424228
>      1.475774284270633   1.475804896751524   1.475876475382906   1.476726165223209
>      1.463578292548192   1.463611627166494   1.463689466240788   1.464609083309240
>      1.462859608038034   1.462893157900139   1.462971489632478   1.463896516033939
>      1.461912706143012   1.461954067956570   1.462047793798572   1.463079574605320
>      1.450581041157659   1.452770209885761   1.454835202839513   1.459676311335618
>      1.450581041157643   1.452770209885764   1.454835202839484   1.459676311335624
>      1.450581041157651   1.452770209885735   1.454835202839484   1.459676311335610
>      1.450581041157597   1.452770209885784   1.454835202839503   1.459676311335620
>      1.450581041157575   1.452770209885757   1.454835202839496   1.459676311335619
>      1.450581041157716   1.452770209885711   1.454835202839499   1.459676311335613
>      1.450581041157667   1.452770209885744   1.454835202839509   1.459676311335625
>      1.450581041157649   1.452770209885750   1.454835202839476   1.459676311335617
>      1.450581041157655   1.452770209885708   1.454835202839442   1.459676311335622
>      1.450581041157571   1.452770209885700   1.454835202839498   1.459676311335622

as you can here the value are very very close together!

I am trying to plotting this data in a way where I have the two quantities in the x, y axes and the error value is represented by the dot color.

This is how I'm plotting my data:

```
    alpha_list = np.log(alpha_list)        
    eigenvalues, alphaa  = np.meshgrid(eigRange, alpha_list) 

    vMin = np.min(costListTrain)
    vMax = np.max(costListTrain)

    plt.scatter(x, y, s=70, c=normedValues, vmin=vMin, vmax=vMax, alpha=0.50)
```

but the result is not correct.

- I tried to normalize my error value by dividing all values by the `max`, but it didn't work !
- The only way that I could make it work (which is incorrect) is to normalize my data in two different ways. One is base on each column (which means factor1 is constant, factor 2 changing), and the other one based on row (means factor 2 is constant and factor one changing). But it doesn't really make sense because I need a single plot to show the tradeoff between the two quantities on the error values.

## UPDATE

this is what I mean by last paragraph.
normalizing values base on max on each rows which correspond to eigenvalues:

```
maxsEigBasedTrain= np.amax(costListTrain.T,1)[:,np.newaxis]    
maxsEigBasedTest= np.amax(costListTest.T,1)[:,np.newaxis]

normEigCostTrain=costListTrain.T/maxsEigBasedTrain
normEigCostTest=costListTest.T/maxsEigBasedTest
```

normalizing values base on max on each column which correspond to alphas:

```
maxsAlphaBasedTrain= np.amax(costListTrain,1)[:,np.newaxis]
maxsAlphaBasedTest= np.amax(costListTest,1)[:,np.newaxis]

normAlphaCostTrain=costListTrain/maxsAlphaBasedTrain
normAlphaCostTest=costListTest/maxsAlphaBasedTest
```

plot 1:

[image]

where no. `eigenvalue = 10` and alpha changes (should correspond to column 10 of plot 1) :

[image]

where `alpha = 0.0001` and eigenvalues change (should correspond to first row of plot1)

[image]

but as you can see the results are different from plot 1!

## UPDATE:

just to clarify more stuff this is how I read my data:

```
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_regression

rng = np.random.RandomState(0)
diabetes = datasets.load_diabetes()

X_diabetes, y_diabetes = diabetes.data, diabetes.target
X_diabetes=np.c_[np.ones(len(X_diabetes)),X_diabetes]
ind = np.arange(X_diabetes.shape[0])
rng.shuffle(ind)
#===============================================================================
# Split Data 
#===============================================================================
import math
cross= math.ceil(0.7*len(X_diabetes))
ind_train = ind[:cross]
X_train, y_train = X_diabetes[ind_train], y_diabetes[ind_train]

ind_val=ind[cross:]
X_val,y_val=  X_diabetes[ind_val], y_diabetes[ind_val]
```

I also uploaded `.csv` files [HERE](http://www.filesend.net/download.php?f=ae13c85aaadcc1d73d9281b372ae8892)

`log.csv` contain the original value before normalization for plot 1

`normalizedLog.csv` for plot 1

`eigenConst.csv` for plot 2

`alphaConst.csv` for plot 3

Comment: What do you mean by "the result is not correct"?

Comment: I mean for example for if I plot the case when we have 10 eigenvalue(constant ) and change the value of alpha in a separate  plot the behavior is different from here if you look at the column where no.of eigenvalue is 10.and the same for the rows

Comment: @BrenBarn I add more details

Comment: Did you leave something out after "error value is assigned a color"?

Comment: Is it possible that you have the axes of `costListTrain` wrong?

Comment: @tiago I don't think so. you can see it in my code

Comment: @Moj: Never mind. It's been corrected in editing.

Comment: You don't show how you generate figures 2 and 3. Does anything happen to the data in the mean time?

Comment: @Evert no. I plot those in 2 separate functions

Comment: can you put a csv file or something with the full `costListTrain` someplace as well as post how you generate `x` and `y`?  There is a flip between what you call rows and cols in your plots an in the array.

Comment: Also, be aware of the limits of doubles https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_precision .

Comment: I can't make sense of your costListTrain example: shouldn't these numbers be clipped inside the 0-1 range? Yet, your code doesn't show anything like that. Can you make a stand-alone example that shows this problem (and produces all three figures). Eg, use `linspace` to create a bunch of costListTrain data.

Comment: @Evert sorry I didn't write to code for normalizing values

Comment: @tcaswell I put the csv files

Comment: What I mean is, can you make a self-contained script that we can copy-paste, and that *only* produces just 3 plots like here? I.e., without scikits etc, just some representable data as input. You've ot almost everything here already, just in bits and pieces, so the logic flow is missing and we can't really see where things go wrong (I can indeed see figure 2 doesn't correspond to column 10, even when normalized; now I want to know what's behind the scenes). So, essentially your current script, stripped to bare-bones for just producing the bar-minimum plots.

Comment: @Evert I really don't know how o provide a simple question script to show the intuition behind my code,because it's kind of complicated problem for me.but for hint I am trying to implement Ridge regression base on two different regularization method

Comment: I can upload my whole project here

Comment: @Moj: that's not what I meant. You can just declare a `costlisttrain` and the other variables, and then *only* use the commands to create the plots. No need for code that creates the `costlisttrain` array, no need for "logic" code. Your code sections 2 to 5 almost do that, just not enough that I can turn it into a script that produces your plotting problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. First of all there was one problem in my code. I was expecting the  "No. of eigenvalue" correspond to rows but in my for loop they fill the columns. The currect answer is this :

```
for i in range(alphaLen):
    for j in range(n): 
        alpha=alpha_list[i]
        c=train.eig(xt_, yt_,m-j,m,alpha,"cpu")
        costListTrain[i,j]=cost.err(xt_,xt_,yt_,c)
        costListTest[i,j]=cost.err(xt_,xv_,yv_,c)
```

After asking questions from friends and colleagues I got this answer :

> I would assume on default imshow and other plotting commands you
>   might want to use, do equally sized intervals on the values you are
>   plotting. if you can set that to logarithmic you should be fine.
>   Ideally, equally "populated bins" would proof most effective, i guess.

for plotting I just subtract the `min value` from the error and the add a small number and at the end take the log.

```
 temp=costListTrain- costListTrain.min()
 temp+=0.00000001
 extent = [0, 20,alpha_list[0], alpha_list[-1]]

 plt.imshow(np.log(temp),interpolation="nearest",cmap=plt.get_cmap('spectral'), extent =  extent, origin="lower")
 plt.colorbar()
```

and result is :

[image]